# How to know the price of a given day assuming continuous growth on log scale

Tags: functions

First i want to say that my math level is too basic and I dont know how to ask my problem in the right way, but i'll try to explain it in my words:

I have a chart with two axes: Day and Price

Both axes are on arithmetic scale

I know two things:

On day $1$, price is $\$1$

On day $30$, price is $\$2$

From that information, I know the price has changed $100\%$ from day $1$ to day $30$

Assuming *continuous* growth (a straight line) from day $1$ to day $30$ I want to know the price (or percentage  change) for any day in between $1$ and $30$.

So I do this, $\frac{100}{30} = 3,33$ (my logic: $100\%$ change / $30$ days)

I draw a line from day $1$ to day $3$ in the chart and verify it, for example on day $11$, the change is $33,33\%$ this is fine, this is the expected number from my calculation ($\frac{100}{30}$ * ndays from day $1$)... So I can know the change or price for any day I want

[Arithmetic scale line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjj7T.png)

Now, I want to do that same thing (I want know any day price change) but with the price axe on logarithmic scale, having only information about day 1 price and day 30 price

When I change the scale of the price, from arithmetic to logscale, my growth line doesnt match that $33,33\%$ anymore

[semilog scale line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj00B.png)

As I understand it, if the scale is logaritmic, maybe the growth should be logaritmic too or something like that... not lineal so my calculation ($\frac{100}{30}$) is not valid any more

How can I do this? What is the calculation I should do to get the right %change for any day using log scale graphic?

Summary of my question:

I want to know how to calculate any day price (or its % change) of a growth line in log scale that was constructed connecting two prices (from day $1$ to day $30$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If linear growth, simply p(t)=$29t-28$

If exponential groth, let p(t)=$Ae^{at}$ , with conditions $p(1)= 1, p(30)=2$

1=$Ae^{(a)}$ , 2=$Ae^{30(a)}$

2= $e^{29a}$ , $\ln 2 =29a$, $a=\frac{\ln2}{29}$,

1=$Ae^{\frac{\ln2}{29}}$ , $A=e^{-\frac{\ln2}{29}}$

So, the answer $\to$

$p(t)=e^{(t-1)\frac{ln2}{29}}$

Comment: Hi BS, thank you for your answer, I'm trying to understand your calculations. Sorry im too basic at maths. In the beggining you say for linear growth p(t) = 29t - 28 , I dont know if I get it... for example, for day 11, should I do 29*11 - 28 ?

Comment: Let y=ax+b, when x=1, y=1;x=2,y=30. So 1=a+b, 30=2a+b, a=29, b=-28.  Yes, your cal for 11day is  right .

Comment: 29*11 - 28 = 291. How could that be if the last price is 2 on day 30 how is that on day 11 price is 291?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake 1=a+b, 2=30a+b, a=1/29, b=28/29 , y=1/29*x +28/29.

Comment: Please check this out https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html